# Passing model to javascript through view bag coming empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, json.net

I am passing my class object after being serialized into json then accessing it into javascript which is coming blank.

my class

```
public class PMICheckListWrapper
        {
            public PMIMachine Machine { get; set; }
            public List<PMICheckListResponse> CheckResponseList { get; set; }
        }
```

controller Code:

```
public ActionResult GetViewEditData(int machineID)
        {
          var result = Json(PMIComputerModel.GetViewEditDetails(machineID), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
          ViewBag.MachineData = result.Data;
          return View("PMIComputerList");
        }
```

JavaScript where i am accessing it.

```
$(function(){
  if('@ViewBag.MachineData' != null)
        {
         var data = '@ViewBag.MachineData'; 
         alert(data);//this is coming empty
         alert(jQuery.parseJSON(data)); // this is coming null
        }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
var data = @Html.Raw(@ViewBag.MachineData);
```

Answer (score 0):

How sure are you that GetViewEditDetails is actually getting something? Try:

```
public ActionResult GetViewEditData(int machineID)
    {
      var result = new JsonResult();
      var data = PMIComputerModel.GetViewEditDetails(machineID);
      if(data != null){
            result.Data = data;
      }
      else {
         // give some kind of feedback that there is no result
      }
      ViewBag.MachineData = result;
      return View("PMIComputerList");
    }
```